# Swaping the order of exponents

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this exercise asking me to find equivalient expressions to

$3^{t^2 + 3t}$

It presents me first with this one, which turns out to be equivalent

${3^t}^2*27^t$

And then it presents me this one, which turns out to **NOT** be equivalent

$9^t*27^t$

But I do not understand why... I thought that you could turn the second expression into the first one, like this:

$9^t=={3^2}^t==3^{2t}==3^{t2}=={3^t}^2$

Where did I make a mistake??

Comment: What you were told is wrong, at least for positive real numbers. For negative $a$ and complex exponents the question is more subtle.

Comment: Sorry, I should have given more details. I have updated the question with the real original problem I had.

Comment: Why do you believe that $2^t = 2t$?

Comment: $3^{t^2}=3^{(t^2)}\ne(3^t)^2$.

Comment: If I understood correctly from my previous lessons... $(a^b)^c$ is the same as $a^{bc}$

Comment: Your understanding is correct but that does not imply that $a^b=ab$ which is effectively what you have done

Comment: But... if ${a^b}^c==a^{bc}$... I thought what when, for example $3^x==3^y$, then the logical conclusion is that $x==y$. Am I confused?

Comment: The brackets are very important - see the comment by @colt_browning above

Comment: I see... so when there are no brackets, the precedence is from the top to the bottom? I thought there was an associative property there...

Comment: Yes - that is correct

Comment: eg $3^{3^2}=3^9$ which is not the same as $3^{3*2}=3^6$

Comment: And that means that I can only con vert $b^c$ into $bc$ when the precedence is from bottom to the top, marked by parenthesis?

Comment: With exponents you should always work from top to bottom making sure you evaluate any bracketed expressions first

Comment: Please, stop using $==$, use $=$.

Comment: @jjagmath Sorry. Habit from programming.

Comment: That what I imagined. Also, in Mathematics we don't use $*$ to denote multiplication. Please, use (ideally) juxtaposition, `\cdot` ($\cdot$) or `\times` ($\times$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convention from exponentiation is that $a^{b^c}$ means $a^{(b^c)}$, not $(a^b)^c$. Note that those are in general different.

We have $(a^b)^c = a^{b c}$ (under certain hypothesis), but in general $a^{(b^c)}$ can't be further simplified.